# _deleted_conflicts in CouchDB?

Tags: couchdb

Using CouchDB 1.0.1.

I have DELETEd some documents, then I PUT some other documents with the same `_id` as the deleted ones.

Now these new docs have the `_deleted_conflicts` field:

```
"_deleted_conflicts":["2-667c9e8e75f8ee51a4ab79ed534622dd"]
```

It looks like the `_rev` field of the deleted doc (can't be sure though).

The [CouchDB wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_Document_API#Special_Fields) just says "Information about conflicts".

1. Is this a problem?
2. Why CouchDB saves this information?
3. Am I supposed to do something about it?

Thanks,
Giacomo

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is actually going to be a problem, but it's likely this could come up during replication.

If you want to prevent it from coming up, you should look into the [/db/_purge](http://www.couchbase.org/sites/default/files/uploads/all/documentation/couchbase-api-db.html#couchbase-api-db_db-purge_post) command. This command will remove references to deleted documents, and you can specify a single document ID to affect.

Comment: I'll try to _purge, but still I'd like to figure out why there's a conflict on a deleted document when no replication happened. [Here](http://wiki.couchdb.couchdb.org/page/How_to_replicate_a_database) I found something about `_deleted_conflicts` (search for Conflict Resolution on the page), but in a different scenario.

Comment: If you delete a document and then attempt to create a new document with the same ID as the deleted document, you will get this deleted_conflicts field in the new document... unless you purge the deleted document before trying to create the new document.

Comment: Is it advisable to _purge a document? I have a system where I would often like to create a document with a particular _id, delete it, and then create it again if a condition changes. Why do the designers of CouchDB discourage against using doing this with the _deleted_conflicts field?

Comment: *purging* the versions in **_deleted_conflicts** array will remove all the deleted conflicts history.

Answer (score 0):

Deleted Conflicts should be regularly purged otherwise a very long history will slow couchdb down significantly (at least for earlier versions of couchdb I used).

Comment: I also wonder why couchdb developers want to retain deleted conflicts. Why is  deleting a doc and late on re-creating it is a conflict?